# ArrayList Size Increment

Tags: java, arraylist

I have code below and I am trying to understand one thing. Why does this statement...

```
System.out.print(l1.size());
```

...after the for-loop in my `interleave` method give me a different size for `l1` every time? Should it not return a constant size for my ArrayList?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Alternate_ArrayList {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        final List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList( 10, 20, 30) );
        final List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList( 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8 );
        System.out.println( interleave( l1, l2 ));
        //System.out.println(Math.min(3, 4));

    }

    public static <T> List<T> interleave( final List<T> l1, final List<T> l2 ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < l2.size(); i++ ) {
            System.out.print(l1.size());
            //System.out.println("----" +Math.min(i*2+1, l1.size()));
            l1.add( Math.min( i*2+1, l1.size()), l2.get( i ));
          //  l1.a

        }
        return l1;
    }
}
```

Comment: We'll, you `add` to `l1` after the call so surely that increases the size, right?

Comment: ^^ @BoristheSpider is right. l1.add will increment the size.

Comment: ArrayLists are different than arrays. They do not have a constant size.

Answer (score 2):

As you add elements to the ArrayList the size of the ArrayList grows. This is why you get increasing/decreasing values when you add/remove elements.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is a Collection, not an array, so its `size` refers to the number of elements that have been added to it, not the capacity of its internal array.

[`ArrayList#size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size%28%29):

> Returns the number of elements in this list.

It will therefore increase by 1 every time you add something to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add just adds another value to the list. If you keep adding values it will make space to take them.